# When to use ArrayList and when to use simple integer array

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain in which situation are we supposed to use ArrayList instead of a simple array and what is the difference between these two and how to initialize the ArrayList.

I am new to java so use example if possible.

Comment: Please read on benefits and disadvantages of both... And ask only programming questions.

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't know the size to be created, you can use ArrayList.

If you just want speed access, you can use array (indexing in array is faster than ArrayList).

And also, ArrayList reduces the complexity of coding.

ArrayList can be initialized like this

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

Add values to the ArrayList

```
al.add("String"); 
al.add(number);
```